# Configure permissions to use Self service site creation

Tags: sharepoint-server

On SharePoint on premise, is there a way to limit who can use Self-Service Site Creation?

We would like to use a product that utilises the self-service functionality, but do not want to open that functionality up to all users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look here - [User permissions and permission levels](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sites/user-permissions-and-permission-levels).

As you can see **Read** permission level has this option is active already.

So you can create your own permission levels (by copy one of defaults, e.g.) with this option is checked/unchecked.

Comment: Ah yes I was sure I had seen it somewhere but couldn't find it.  There is an option in permissions levels for: "Use Self-Service Site Creation  -  Create a Web site using Self-Service Site Creation."

I assume that if users have the default Read permissions level or higher permissions on the top level site collection, they will be able to create new site collections in the web application.

To restrict the usage of self service site creation, new permission levels are needed with the "Use Self-Service Site Creation  -  Create a Web site using Self-Service Site Creation." option unchecked.

Answer (score 2):

In your User Profile Service, in the People group head over to Manage User Permissions. Select All Users Windows (or NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users depending on version), and "Uncheck the "Create Personal Site" for the existing users".

That way you disallow ordinary users do create personal sites.

See [How to Limit the Self-Service Site Creation to only users of a specific AD group](http://sharepointfordummies.blogspot.com/2012/02/how-to-limit-self-service-site-creation.html)